# Uniform radio doesn't work after clone

Tags: jquery, html, uniform

I am cloning a block of HTML and then appending it to a form. Radio button doesn't work after .clone.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/JNCFP/169/

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="formElement">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" />
        <input type="text" name="text[]" />
        <button class="button" type="button">Clone</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    // Uniform every form element
    $('input, select').uniform();

    // clone Div
    $('form .button').click(function () {
        var el = $(this).parents('.formElement');
        $(el).clone(true).insertAfter($(el));
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  What isn't it doing that you want it to do?

Comment: I can't select cloned radio button. If I disable uniform everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.uniform()` again after you clone it so it can initialize the plugin on the new elements:

```
// Uniform every form element
$(function () {
    // Show browser information
    $('input, select').uniform();

    $('form').on('click', '.button', function () {
        var el = $(this).parents('.formElement');
        $(el).clone().insertAfter($(el));
        $('input, select').uniform();
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JNCFP/171/)

Comment: Yes, that works, but when you clone without `withDataAndEvents` set to true, cloned `<button>` will not work.

Comment: You would also need to re-bind the `click` event. Instead, I suggest event delegation. The answer has been updated to include it. Those buttons should all work now.